# Login with several options, show/hide other fields

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

My page will contain 2 login alternatives.

Alt. 1 : Fields for database name, username and password.
Alt 2: Field for the database connectionstring.

When you start typing in a field in alternative 1, i want the connectionstring field to hide and opposite... if you start typing in the connectionstring field i want the other 3 fields to hide.

Is there a easy way to accomplish this with knockout validation ?

Thanks on forehand!

Comment: it would be useful if you create a fiddle

Comment: In short, yes, it's possible with `knockout`'s `visible` binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your values are part of your view model, you can use the `visible` attribute in `data-bind` to check the length of the values:

Sample Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RkaB3/1/

View Model:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.alt1 = ko.observable('');
    self.alt2 = ko.observable('');
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Markup:

```
<div data-bind="visible: alt2().length == 0">
    <p>Alt1 Login</p>
    <input data-bind="value: alt1"></input>
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: alt1().length == 0">
    <p>Alt2 Login</p>
    <input data-bind="value: alt2"></input>
</div>
```

You may want to do something a bit more intelligent on the `Alt1` option that contains 3 fields. For example, use a `ko.computed` function that checks all 3 fields and return true if any of them contain a value:

**Updated Fiddle with computed**

```
self.usingLoginAlternative1 = ko.computed(function () {
    return !self.connectionString();
});

self.usingLoginAlternative2 = ko.computed(function () {
    return !(self.server() || self.database() || self.userId() || self.password());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RkaB3/4/

Comment: yes, I have updated my fiddle to include a ko.computed to show what I meant